# Creating a crop view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I am trying to implement my own cropping screen.

See below image:

[image: screen sample]

The layout has a background and the image has listeners to move around the screen and zoom. I have a framelayout for the 'cropping transparency layer' and frame.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- This is the transparent border -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/crop_transparent_top"
    android:bottom="550dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#AA0A0A0A" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/crop_transparent_bottom"
    android:top="550dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#AA0A0A0A" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/crop_transparent_right"
    android:bottom="110dp"
    android:left="1000dp"
    android:top="110dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#AA0A0A0A" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/crop_transparent_left"
    android:bottom="110dp"
    android:right="1000dp"
    android:top="110dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#AA0A0A0A" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- This is a border -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/crop_frame"
    android:bottom="100dp"
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:top="100dp">
    <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/img_border" />
</item>

</layer-list>
```

I am not the most familiar with drawable. What I am doing is drawing 4 different boxes, one on top and bottom, and 2 for each side of the frame.

Is this the correct way to do this or could it be done with less code?

It's important to note that I will support dynamic shaped frames so I will ultimately be changing the values in Java code.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this with code:

```
private Drawable createBackground(int widthForRatio, int heightForRatio, int displayWidth, int displayHeight) {

    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_border);

    NinePatchDrawable frame = new NinePatchDrawable(getResources(), b, b.getNinePatchChunk(), new Rect(), null);

    Drawable[] layers = { getTransparent(), getTransparent(), getTransparent(), getTransparent(), frame };
    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

    final TypedArray styledAttributes = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize });
    int mActionBarSize = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
    styledAttributes.recycle();

    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, displayHeight - 100 - mActionBarSize);
    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 0, displayHeight - 100 - mActionBarSize, 0, 0);
    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(2, displayWidth - 50, 100, 0, 100);
    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(3, 0, 100, displayWidth - 50, 100);
    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(4, 50, 100, 50, 100);

    return layerDrawable;
}

private ShapeDrawable getTransparent() {
    ShapeDrawable transparent = new ShapeDrawable();
    transparent.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#AA0A0A0A"));
    return transparent;
}
```